# what is the use of multiple endpoints in WCF service?

Tags: wcf

i have seen people decorate their config file with multiple endpoints in WCF service. is there any reason. when one endpoint is ok then why two or more endpoints are require?

tell me small situation when multiple endpoints is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario for multiple endpoints:

- Service wants to expose more than one type of binding.
- Service wants to expose more than one contract on the same binding.
- Service wants to expose same binding and contract on different addresses.

http://debugmode.net/2010/05/25/multipleendpoint/

Comment: yes i got ur point but like to know why people like to create more than one type of binding and when ? give me some sample situation when one has to got for more than one type of binding is required.

Comment: give me sample config entries for expose more than one contract on the same binding. give me sample config entries for same binding and contract on different addresses for better understanding and visualization. thanks

Comment: The advantage of providing different endpoints is that each endpoint can use different binding. You can have one endpoint for .NET client another for PHP client. You can have diferent encyption type and etc. For example you can have one interface that exposes many operations and you have basic interface which does basic things and you publish the second to outside and first one for internal use with exntented functionality.